# Why does a Gauge group have to be a compact Lie group?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

In *Topological Solitons* by *Nicholas Manton* where he considers "compact Lie groups" to be the gauge groups
 for generalizing gauge theoretic concepts. But, he does not mention why that condition is required

The killing is non-degenerate as per the requirement of the kinetic terms.Kinetic part of the Yang Mills action $$ \int Tr({\bf{F^2}}) dV$$ to be positive definite. I do think there is relevancy of the compactness of the lie group as apposed to the views in [Why is the Yang-Mills gauge group assumed compact and semi-simple?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/52452/why-is-the-yang-mills-gauge-group-assumed-compact-and-semi-simple)

I've found this result. http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/notes9.pdf

> For compact groups the Killing form will be negative definite

I'm not able to find any such result for a Lie group. Can anyone tell me how this and the above result are result and its implementation in gauge theory?

Thanks,
Sai

Comment: compact groups have finite reps?

Comment: @innisfree and why finite representations are required?

Comment: I don't see how this question is different from the [one you link](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52452/50583), might you explain?