# On what kind groups of Lie groups are Yang-Mills theories based?

Tags: standard-model, group-theory, lie-algebra, yang-mills

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yang%E2%80%93Mills_theory:

> Yang–Mills theory is a gauge theory based on [...] any compact, **semi-simple** Lie group.

But the symmetry group of Standard Model, i.e. ${SU(3)}\times{SU(2)}\times{U(1)}$, is **not** semisimple, due to the $U(1)$ factor, right? What am I missing here?

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52452/2451

Comment: You're missing nothing, it's not semisimple, having an Abelian factor is a special case that's not included in the Wikipedia definition of a Yang-Mills theory. What is the physics question here?

Comment: "On what kind groups of Lie groups are Yang-Mills theories based?"