The meaning of $i$ in the Yang-Mills
In Yang mills theory (including maxwell's theory), the generators of $SU(n)$ are complex matrices acting on the spinor $\psi$.
Now the phase of $\psi$ is also given by $e^{i\theta}$.
Why do we use this same $i$ in both cases? In other words, for the $SU(n)$ it would be possible to define a different $i$ to the phase, by choosing a matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$
And adding some extra parameter to the spinor $\psi^a$.
Is there some close link which explains why Yang-Mills has to affect the phase like this?
Long story short, in QM we make the change $k\rightarrow i \partial$, and I'm wondering what the explanation (mathematical or physical) why this is the same $i$ that appears in the complex generators of $SU(n)$. Because from first sight these seem like they don't have anything to do with each other.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/52452/2451

The symbol for the Lie group SU(n) means "special unitary" group. So the elements in this group are unitary. Often we represent such an element in exponential form $\exp(i\alpha_n\tau_n)$ where $\tau_n$ represents the generators. For the two-dimensional representation of SU(2) they are given by the Pauli matrices. These generators are Hermitian matrices. For the exponential expression of a unitary transformation the exponent must be anti-Hermitian. That is why we need to $i$ in the exponent.

Yes, that is true, but it doesn't explain why it is the same $i$ that it in the expression, $k\rightarrow i\partial$ We could use a different $j$ where $i$ and $j$ commute.

@bob The field of complex numbers has only one imaginary unit; i isn’t a matrix.

@Ghoster Given a even 2n dimensional vector space you can turn this into a n dimensional complex space by grouping the dimensions in two sets. There are more than one way of doing this and hence more than one representation of the value $i$. Your $i$ is then represented as a 2nx2n dimensional matrix. You can absolutely represent $i$ as a matrix. All complex n dimensional spaces are isomorphic to 2n dimensional real spaces.

No, even in your $2n$ dimensional space, $i$ on all those complex spaces is always $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

In physically important example, $SU(2)$, the use of the imaginary here simply depends upon the fact that physics convention of coordinatising $Spin(3)$ with the isomorphic complex group, $SU(2)$. So the use of the imaginary here for the Yang-Mills theory over $SU(2)$ is spurious.
This argument doesn't generalise to higher $SU(n)$.

Can the downvoter please explain why my post is wrong or irrelevant to the question?
